# How to I declare a abstract generic superclass for an other generic class?

Tags: java, class, generics, superclass

How to I declare a abstract generic superclass for an other generic class?

```
    public class CampionsLeague<Team> extends League<Team> {
    ...
```

At `League<Team>` I get the error:

> "Bound mismatch: The type Team is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter < Team extends Comparable< Team>> of the type League< Team>"

Comment: you are probably looking for `public class CampionsLeague extends League<Team> {`

Comment: Well you haven't shown the definition of `League`, but the error message tells you that `Team` needs to extend `Comparable<Team>`...

Answer (score 3):

As the error clearly states, you can't write `League<X>` unless `X` satisfies the constraints declared in `League`'s declaration.

You need to constrain the derived class' generic parameter to match the constraints in the base class:

```
public class ChampionsLeague<Team extends Comparable<Team>> extends League<Team>
```

Comment: Thank you so far. Now i tryed to

Comment: make an Object ChampionsLeague< Team> league = new ChampionsLeague<>(); but it isnt working :(

Comment: What is `Team`? You need to understand generics.

Comment: `Team` is other generic class `Team<T extends AbstractMember> implements Comparable<Mannschaft>, Iterable<T>`

Comment: > "Bound mismatch: The type Team is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <Team extends Comparable<Team>> of the type ChampionsLeague<Team>"

Comment: This is not right answer. When you write public class CampionsLeague<Team extends Comparable<Team>> extends League<Team> compiler does not treat first two Teams as Team class name - they are just placeholders. Try create ChampionsLeague<Integer> to see that I'm right.

Comment: @MarcinJedynak: I know.  I'm assuming that he doesn't actually have a `Team` class.

Answer (score -2):

If you have generic class

```
class League<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

and you want to create its generic subclass, you have to ensure that all the constraints are satisfied:

```
class ChampionsLeague<T extends Comparable<T>> extends League<T>
```

But when you want to subclass class with provided generic type, for example there is a class:

```
class Team implements Comparable<Team>
```

you should not repeat this type in the derived class name:

```
class ChampionsLeague extends League<Team>
```

Something like this:

```
class ChampionsLeague<Team> extends League<Team>
class ChampionsLeague<Team extends Comparable<Team>> extends League<Team>
```

will be treated by compiler as hiding previous generic type of the `League` by a new placeholder. Fortunately, you should be warned by you IDE and you can see something like this:

```
The type parameter Team is hiding the type Team.
```

Comment: Could you tell me what errors are we talking about? Author did not provide any code, but for me we have situation: Team implements Comparable<Team>, League<T extends Comparable<T>> and in that case CampionsLeague extends League<Team> is what should be done.

Comment: @MarcinJedynak, perhaps you can explain in more detail why you're suggesting this answer.